# how to set frame for cell.imageView.frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i tried this below code in cell for row...

```
if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Home"])
    {
         cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Home-50.png"];
cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake( 10, 15, 20, 20 );
}
```

This is below code is in didselect row at Indexpath...

```
if ([[arrCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Home"]) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Home1-50.png"];
  cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake( 10, 15, 20, 20 );
}
```

I am using this above code to display image in tableview cell and when cell is clicked Then Image change to another image...Images are Changing But,the frames are not applying...

Comment: imageView - is the default imageview or custom imageview

Comment: change any flag value in did select and reload the tableview and change frame in cell for row at index path on that flag it will be easier

Comment: [cell.imageView layoutifNeed]; put this after your resize a frame

Comment: What I can see in your code is that frame size in both methods is same. Then what size it is supposed to update to ?

Comment: please can u explain it clearly-ravi.p

Comment: can you put the entire implementation for cell for row and didSelectRow method?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this because it is fixed layout of UITableViewCell.If you want to do this go with below option

**OPTION 1:** **CustomCell**

```
  Through CustomCell you can set image view frame whatever you want.
```

**OPTION 2:** **Programmatically creating image view add it to cell**

```
 UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
 img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"];
 [img setFrame:CGRectMake( 10, 15, 20, 20)];
[[cell.contentView addSubview:img];];
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved by transform scaling：

```
 cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "icon_shareToFriends")
 if let imageView = cell.imageView, imageView.transform == .identity {
    imageView.transform = imageView.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.55, y: 0.55)
    imageView.contentMode = .center
 }
```